# React/redux router isn't going into page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron

I am using the react router module with electron. I click on a text which I linked it with the Link function so that it can route to that page (which is /torrenado) but it doesn't go through. The only reaction I get is a console message. Here is all the code including the console.log message I get in response:

**Home.js component containing the routing link which leads to ./containers/Torrenado.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Home.css';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.container} data-tid="container">
          <h2>Home</h2>
          <h4>Go to <Link to="/torrenado">Torrenado</Link></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**routes.js**

```
/* eslint flowtype-errors/show-errors: 0 */
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';


import App from './containers/App';
import HomePage from './containers/HomePage';
import CounterPage from './containers/CounterPage';
import Torrenado from './containers/Torrenado';

export default () => (
  <Router>
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/counter" component={CounterPage} />
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/torrenado" component={Torrenado} />
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </Router>
);
```

**./containers/Torrenado.js**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as TorrenadoActions from '../actions/torrenado';
import Torrenado from '../components/Torrenado';


function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return {
    torrenado: state.torrenado
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps( dispatch ) {
  return bindActionCreators( TorrenadoActions, dispatch );
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( Torrenado );
```

**../components/Torrenado.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Torrenado extends Component {
  props: {
    renderOne: () => void,
    renderTwo: () => void
  };
  render() {
    const { renderOne, renderTwo } = this.props;
    console.log( renderOne() );
    console.log( renderTwo() );
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Torrenado app</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Torrenado;
```

**message from console.log:**

```
Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack
```

Comment: which version of `react-router`?

Comment: Also what exactly did you see from the `console.log`? `() => void` twice?

Comment: I am using react-router v4.1.1. and for the console.log msg i juts added into my original post. It was: "Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack"